# AWS EC2 migration to new instance type with SSD Drives

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have MySQL running on an m1.xlarge instance with a 100GB EBS volume holding the data files. I would like to migrate to a m3.2xlarge instance and place the data files on the new 2 x 80GB SSD drives.

I stopped my instance, changed the type accordingly, and launched it. However all I could find for storage was a 15G tempfs and an 8G mounted drive.

```
$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/xvda1: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

How do I get access to the 2 x 80GB SSDs for this instance type?

Comment: `fdisk -l`, `mkfs`, then `mount`.

Comment: When you changed the instance type and launched it, only the RAM and CPU type changes. In order to resize the disk in general the idea is:

- make a snapshot of your instance
- create a bigger volume from the snapshot in the same zone
- attach new volume to instance /dev/sda1
- start the instance (DNS name changes)

Comment: @LinuxDevOps: Thanks. By changing the way I did, will the attached volume still be available as it was before the instance change?

Comment: Check in your AWS web console under EC2 management -> Volumes if it's there (identify by capacity and 'available'), you may have lost it

Comment: Dupes: http://serverfault.com/questions/571427/root-device-on-ssd-instance-types-ssd-vs-ebs-confusion http://serverfault.com/questions/490597/wheres-my-ephemeral-storage-for-ec2-instance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, for a full answer, basically your SSD drives are ephemeral disks, and according to the AWS documentation the only way to use these ephemeral disk is to create a new instance. (The feature to attach ephemeral storage to the instance after it has been create it's not available yet)

This is from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStore_UsageScenarios):

> Instances that use Amazon EBS for the root device do not, by default,
>   have instance store available at boot time. Also, you can't attach
>   instance store volumes after you've launched an instance. Therefore,
>   if you want your Amazon EBS-backed instance to use instance store
>   volumes, you must specify them using a block device mapping when you
>   create your AMI or launch your instance. Examples of block device
>   mapping entries are: /dev/sdb=ephemeral0 and /dev/sdc=ephemeral1. For
>   more information about block device mapping, see Block Device Mapping

Like @LinuxDevOps mentioned you have to create a snapshot of your existing instance and then create a new one attaching the SSD volumes.  After you login to your new instance you can do like @ceejayoz mentioned.

List your devices:

```
fdisk -l
```

Make a file system on the devices. For example ext4

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdb
mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdc
```

Mount the devices:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/xvdb; mkdir -p /mnt/xvdc
mount /dev/xvdb /mnt/xvdb
mount /dev/xvdc /mnt/xvdc
```

For reference: [list of device names according to instance types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html#InstanceStoreDeviceNames)

There also other similar answers in SF and SO. For example: [Where's my ephemeral storage for EC2 Instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/490597/wheres-my-ephemeral-storage-for-ec2-instance)